# Debugging html with IE and IE driver in Selenium

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer

We are using Eclipse, Java and Selenium.  Most of our sites can be accessed with Chrome.  With Chrome you can right-click something and select "inspect".  it will show the html and you can type an xpath into the search box (after ctrl-f) and it will highlight the elements.

With IE you can inspect and it will show the html (sometimes you need to refresh).  But you can't search for xpaths, etc.

I can write the html to a file, strip out everything with  in it, and use Chrome on it but that is limited in what it does.

Wondering how others debug with IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also search for the elements in IE 11. You can't use xpath but you can enter the css selector in the search bar on the top of right in **DOM Explorer** Tab, then it will auto focus on the element you want:
[image]